# why does returning JsonResult from a Dictionary change the sort order?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have the following controller action:

```
public JsonResult GetInvestors(int bank)
{
    var investors = _context.Investors
    .Where(i => i.BankNumber == bank)
    .Select(i => new { InvestorId = i.InvestorId.ToString(), InvestorName = i.InvestorName + " (" + i.BankNumber + ")" })
    .OrderBy(i => i.InvestorName)
    .ToDictionary(i => i.InvestorId, i => i.InvestorName);

    return Json(investors, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And the following javascript to call that action that for now just starts the debugger so I can browse the result:

```
function getInvestors(bank)
{
    $.ajax
    ({
        url: "/InvestorDetail/GetInvestors",
        type: "POST",
        data: { bank: bank },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (returnedData) { debugger; }
    });
}
```

If I watch `investors` in the controller action, it is sorted by the investor name, which is what I want.  However, when I get to the javascript debugger and watch `returnedData`, the data comes in sorted by the investor ID.

Alternately, if I put OrderBy after ToDictionary and order by Value, in the javascript debugger the json structure of the result is different but it is sorted by investor name like I want.

Why would the sort order change when returned from a Dictionary?

Thank you.

Comment: JavaScript properties are ordered based only on the way the object was built. If you need a specific ordering, put the values in an array and sort them however you want as necessary.

Comment: Did my answer below assist you in a solution you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For purposes of enumeration, each item in the dictionary is treated as a KeyValuePair structure representing a value and its key. The order in which the items are returned is undefined.

See [official msdn documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)

You can use sorted Dictionaries though, or sort it properly on the client side.

Comment: This is so not a good answer.  Stating a fact and adding MS documentation?

Comment: @JSkyS The question was... Why does the order change? The answer is because its not guaranteed for dictionaries. Its as simple as that. I stand by my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't sort a dictionary, although you can get a representation of a sorted dictionary!

You could try something like

```
import collections

Dictionary_Sorted = collections.OrderedDict(x)
```

x being an object with key valued pairs.

This is the same case for C# as well.

I like to change my Dictionary to a list by say.

```
var newList = thisDictionary.ToList();
newList.Sort((a,b) => a.Value.CompareTo(b.Value));
```

I like the one liner approach.  It is simple and elegant.
If you would like to sort it descending then switch the values as such.

```
   newList.Sort((a,b) => b.Value.CompareTo(a.Value));
```

Comment: Using a list worked, I just replaced my ToDictionary with ToList, and my sort was preserved.  Thank you.

Comment: @Mike i believe that my answer is the answer for the question: "Why would the sort order change when returned from a Dictionary?" The solution is useful, but for purposes of spreading knowledge with others having the same issue the answer should be marked properly.